# How Should I store My User's Images?

Tags: php, database

I've been reviewing all sorts of ways and researching, but I haven't been able to find solutions. Should I store them in my host's database, my filesystem, or through a third party? If through a third party, which one? Imgur, AWS S3, etc?

Comment: Check out item 4: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hello Twinsett, welcome to Stack Overflow, the answers to your question will be primarily *opinion* based and as such are not really the defined factual answers we are trying to set out on Stack Overflow, so I think it best that you research this topic yourself, using Bing or another search engine as well as nettuts, or researching and reading up on a database specific StackExchange such as http://dba.stackexchange.com/ were useful nuggets will be found. Basically your question is too broad, it depends on a lot of factors (and your experience in each factor) as to the best path for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to store the images' *location* on the *database* and then link it via `PHP` or `ASP` from some *protected directory*.

**Example** (when you are saving picture name and extension with extension):

*Query to select all data:*

**PHP:**

```
{ $profile_picture = $row['pictureLocation']; }
```

*Then wrapping around the path to directory:*

```
$profile_picture = "../assets/protected/images/users/" . $profile_picture ;
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="<?php echo $profile_picture ; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the easiest way (space allowing) is to simply store the actual picture file in your filesystem. Then, in order to reference the file, store the file path in a MySQL database. With that said, there are many ways to store pictures and the best is to experiment with them.